# "ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled)" raised on "image_tag nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

If I don't handle view correctly, Production environment show 500.

`<%= image_tag post.user.image_url %>`

This could be

`<%= image_tag post.user.image_url if post.user && post.user.image_url %>`

but I am little careless and forgot this issue several times.

How can I prevent this? How can I use `<%= image_tag nil %>` in production environment without raising 500?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`image_tag` must have a source, Rails can do nothing with it, but raise an exception.

You can write a helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def safe_image_tag(source, options = {})
    source ||= "default.jpg"
    image_tag(source, options)
  end
end
```

or simply check for `nil` directly in a view. Anyway you have to do *something* to prevent an error.