# Heroku Rails setup ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to setup my first Heroku hosted rails app and am running into what I believe is a precompile/pipeline issue.

I've followed all the appropriate steps:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile    
git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"git push heroku
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
```

Note there is a blank (" ") before "isn't precompiled" in the text of the error message - so it is not specifying the name of the missing precompiled file!

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

It was due to Carrierwave and one of my Models not having a default image.  Not sure I understand why this was an issue - but adding this solved it:

```
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url
```

See this previous thread:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068190/actionviewtemplateerror-isnt-precompiled?lq=1
```