# Asset error while pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

While pushing my app to Heroku I get the following error

```
2013-09-08T12:58:32.140279+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
2013-09-08T12:58:32.140279+00:00 app[web.1]:     206:     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
2013-09-08T12:58:32.140279+00:00 app[web.1]:     209:       <% if   !@orbituarysite.orbiturer_share_images.nil? %> <div class="well"><%   @orbituarysite.orbiturer_share_images.each do |f| %> <%=   image_tag(f.orbiturer_other_images_url(:thumb))  %><% end %></div><% end %>
2013-09-08T12:58:32.140279+00:00 app[web.1]:     210:         <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal5" class="btn btn-primary" href="/orbiturer_share_images/new">Post Notice</a>
```

but while pushing to Heroku precompiling happened

```
   Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8) from git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git (at master)
   Using uglifier (2.2.1)
   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
   Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
   Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_31lb8bborpfrx/Rakefile:7)
   DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_31lb8bborpfrx/Rakefile:7)
   DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_31lb8bborpfrx/Rakefile:7)
   DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_31lb8bborpfrx/Rakefile:7)
   Asset precompilation completed (240.04s)
```

What can be the possible error, pre compilation done , still I am getting error.

Do I need to add any line in production.rb file?

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the error is referencing this:

```
<% if !@orbituarysite.orbiturer_share_images.nil? %>
```

which is saying `if images are NOT nil, do x` - so probably something is coming back `nil` and `precompile` is trying to access and empty file.  Are you using `carrierwave`?

check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11315308/2128691)

> I assume you're using something like CarrierWave to handle file uploads? You can specify a default image handler in your uploader class:
>
> https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

> This will output the default image rather than trying to access a non-existent file called "" in the asset pipeline.

Try to set a default image (as above if using carrierwave, otherwise with whatever you're using to upload image files) and see if that sorts out your error.

Answer (score 0):

In production.rb add the file name to the following line:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['example/file1.css', 'example/file2.js','file3.js']
```